# Is my understanding of multi-dimensional arrays in javascript correct?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I think of arrays as follows.

```
var array1D = [];                            // 1D Array
var array2D = [ [], ... ];                   // 2D Array
var array3D = [ [ [], ... ], ... ];          // 3D Array
```

So the following are all examples of a 2D array.

```
var x = [ [] ];                              // 2D, not 1D!
var y = [ [], [] ];                          // 2D, as expected
var z = [ [], [], [] ];                      // 2D, not 3D!
```

Likewise, the following are all examples of a 3D array.

```
var x = [ [ [] ] ];                          // 3D, not 1D!
var y = [ [ [] ], [ [] ] ];                  // 3D, not 2D!
var z = [ [ [] ], [ [] ], [ [] ] ];          // 3D, as expected
```

Comment: D indicates the depth of the array, not how many items it has...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Nice way to put it :)

Comment: Why would someone downvote this? This question is well formatted?

Comment: A “2D array” is an array of arrays. A “3D array” is an array of 2D arrays. It’s kind of misleading to label them with dimensions in JavaScript, though.

Comment: The answer to the question in the title appears to be "yes"

Comment: @shash678 Thank you so much!

Comment: @ChrisLear Officially answer with that, and I would probably select it. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question in the title appears to be "yes". [Added as an answer here only because @Grateful offered me points - I'm that shallow]

Answer (score 1):

In fact, multi-dimensional arrays don't even exist.

You only have single-dimension arrays. However, since an array can contain elements of any type, you have the possibility of using arrays as items. That's good enough to simulate matrices of any arbitrary dimension.

Comment: I think that's where my problem originally stemmed from. I come from a java background... and things were more logical back then!

Comment: I know little Java but I believe this pseudo-multidimensional arrays concept is common in many languages, including C or PHP.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, array can be built in difference structure. 
except the standard multi-dimensional, It can also like belows:

```
 [{},[[]],[]]
 [[[]],[]]
```